# Hardware implementation of Gaussian noise generator

Tags: noise, gaussian, hardware-implementation

I am implementing a GNG using Verilog. The implementation is based on the IEEE paper "[Hardware Architecture of a Gaussian Noise Generator Based on the Inversion Method](https://doi.org/10.1109/TCSII.2012.2204119)". In this, i could not understand what exactly does the `ROM_trans` block needs to store. I understand it is a lookup table, but I do not know what to store inside it. Also how will I determine the coefficients that need to be stored in the `ROM_coef` block.

Comment: Answer upvotes and better answer validation are required for this question

Answer (score 2):

My friend, you dont need to break your head against a paper...

Just with any example of [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators), the [Blum Blum Shub Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub):

$$x'_{{n+1}}=x_{n}^{'2}{\bmod M}$$

with $M=pq$, $p$, $q$ primes, with $x=\frac{1}{M}x' \approx U(0,1)$ gives you a fairly acceptable uniform $U(0,1)$ random number generator. You can use $p$=13331 and $q$=131 or whatever other.

And for converting the $U(0,1)$ Uniform Random Number into a $N(0,1)$ [Gaussian Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution), as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c), just can use the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to generate N numbers each step, and make the sum ([Bates Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution)). You can use $N$=15:

$$y'_{n}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_{n}^i$$

with $y=\sqrt{12N}(y'-\frac{1}{2}) \approx N(0,1)$

For randomizing, just use a clock or cpu time seed as $x_0'$.

Answer (score 0):

The paper does not give much details. As a partial answer, I would suggest you to parse the Ph. D. thesis of the first author: [Implementación de Funciones Elementales en Dispositivos FPGA](https://riunet.upv.es/bitstream/handle/10251/11519/tesisUPV3605.pdf), Julio 2011.

Even if the thesis is in castellano, you can find several more occurrences of the terms `ROM_coef` and `ROM_trans`, for instance in the algorithm description *Algoritmo Segmentación no-uniforme ICDF* on page 130.

And some online translators can help you convert:

> Finalmente comprobamos si hemos llegado al valor de sigma vs pedido y
>   si es así finalizamos el bucle while y llamamos a una función
>   esc_rom_vhdl que genera los ficheros vhdl que modelan el
>   comportamiento de la memoria ROM_coef y ROM_trans utilizados en
>   nuestra implementación.

into something readable in English:

> Finally we check if we have reached the value of sigma vs. order and
>   if so we finish the loop While and call a function esc_rom_vhdl that
>   generates the vhdl files that model the ROM_coef and ROM_trans memory
>   behavior used in our implementation.